# ROS on the embedded boards

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

I intend to buy a mini ubuntu- based system to install ROS on it. There are lots of boards to chose but I am not sure
which one is the best for installing ROS on it. For example, Cubiboards support Lubuntu (not Ubuntu) which is not suitable for ROS installation. Do you have any suggestion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200575/ros-on-the-embedded-boards/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the data you've provided, it's hard to make any recommendations.

In particular, you don't say anything about the applications that you want to run. What you want to do with your board will dictate how many cores you need, how fast they need to be, which interfaces and peripherals you need, etc.

There are a few types of research that you can do to help narrow down your search:

- determine what sort of sensors and devices you need to plug in, and make sure the board you pick supports them
- search the internet for other people doing similar projects, and look at which computers they're using
- look at the ROS installation instructions and search the internet for guides on installing ROS on each board that you're considering. skim through each guide to get a sense of how well polished it is and how complex it is. Poorly-polished or complex guides indicate that it will take more work to get ROS running on that particular board.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2015-01-08**:
Dear @ahendrix I want to prepare a minimum ROS-based core system for Robotic purposes. Except some standard sensors such as encoders, IMU etc., it would be great if the board could support cameras like Kinect.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lubuntu is Ubuntu but instead of Unity as the desktop environment, it uses LXDE.  It can support ROS.  The board depends on your needs.  If you just need communication and basic processing, something like the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black would work.  If you have more processing, you might want to look at dual or quad core boards like the Odroids, Nvidia Jetson TK1 or Udoo.  Some board have certain features that may be better suited towards your needs. This tough to answer since it really depends on your individual needs.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-01-08**:
I strongly discourage people from using the raspberry pi for robotics; it isn't supported by Ubuntu, it's difficult to get ROS installed, and it doesn't have a lot of computing power when compared to other boards.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2015-01-08**:
I totally agree, the Odroid-C1 is better value.  However, if you have one laying around, it could be some use like a WiFi connection to a microprocessor.  I will note that I was able to compile ROS indigo from the directions for ROS robot with no hiccups.

**Comment by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on 2015-01-08**:
Thanks for comments